# how to store jpeg,gif ,images in thumnail format after uploading

Tags: java

I a uploading images,gif files through java api ,after that i want to save files in thumbnail format.

Comment: I'm sure people will put just as effort into answering this as you have in asking it.

Answer (score 1):

From http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2009/05/20-useful-java-code-snippets-for-java-developers.html:

```
private void createThumbnail(String filename, int thumbWidth, int thumbHeight, int quality, String outFilename)
02          throws InterruptedException, FileNotFoundException, IOException
03      {
04          // load image from filename
05          Image image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(filename);
06          MediaTracker mediaTracker = new MediaTracker(new Container());
07          mediaTracker.addImage(image, 0);
08          mediaTracker.waitForID(0);
09          // use this to test for errors at this point: System.out.println(mediaTracker.isErrorAny());
10   
11          // determine thumbnail size from WIDTH and HEIGHT
12          double thumbRatio = (double)thumbWidth / (double)thumbHeight;
13          int imageWidth = image.getWidth(null);
14          int imageHeight = image.getHeight(null);
15          double imageRatio = (double)imageWidth / (double)imageHeight;
16          if (thumbRatio < imageRatio) {
17              thumbHeight = (int)(thumbWidth / imageRatio);
18          } else {
19              thumbWidth = (int)(thumbHeight * imageRatio);
20          }
21   
22          // draw original image to thumbnail image object and
23          // scale it to the new size on-the-fly
24          BufferedImage thumbImage = new BufferedImage(thumbWidth, thumbHeight, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
25          Graphics2D graphics2D = thumbImage.createGraphics();
26          graphics2D.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
27          graphics2D.drawImage(image, 0, 0, thumbWidth, thumbHeight, null);
28   
29          // save thumbnail image to outFilename
30          BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(outFilename));
31          JPEGImageEncoder encoder = JPEGCodec.createJPEGEncoder(out);
32          JPEGEncodeParam param = encoder.getDefaultJPEGEncodeParam(thumbImage);
33          quality = Math.max(0, Math.min(quality, 100));
34          param.setQuality((float)quality / 100.0f, false);
35          encoder.setJPEGEncodeParam(param);
36          encoder.encode(thumbImage);
37          out.close();
38      }
```

You will need to figure out where all the classes come from, but it doesn't look like they're using anything that's not bundled with the JDK (though I could be wrong).

Answer (score 0):

There's generally no such thing as a "thumbnail format", rather you use an image library to resize uploaded images to a particular small size, compress them, and save alongside the originals.

I'm not familiar with image format libraries in Java but surely there will be others answering to that.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

1. get the `InputStream` from the uploaded item
2. use `ImageIO` to load and rescale the image (google for "java scale image")
3. save the newly scaled image as `imagename_thumb.extension`

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look at [this](http://www.java-forum.org/blogs/void/40-thumbnailcreator.html). It's a german group, but the code provided there is english :-)

Comment: Thanks Tenzen,
                  I found the code,burt i m not getting do i need to fill  a byte array of image and then pass a byte array to this function